# How can i Count Char in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

If i have string 'ABCDAAARSTRLAMA ' how can i count 'A' this char from the given string in sql server 2008

Answer (score 2):

use `len`   and `Replace` function

```
declare @myvar varchar(20)
    set @myvar = 'ABCDAAARSTRLAMA'

    select len(@myvar) - len(replace(@myvar,'A',''))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/063d8/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LENGTH( 'ABCDAAARSTRLAMA' ) - LENGTH( replace( 'ABCDAAARSTRLAMA', 'A', '' ) );
```

**Length Function**

The Length function in SQL is used to get the length of a string. This function has a different name for different databases:

```
MySQL: LENGTH( )
Oracle: LENGTH( )
SQL Server: LEN( )
```

*Syntax*

The syntax for the Length function is as follows:

> LENGTH(str)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT (LENGTH('ABCDAAARSTRLAMA') - LENGTH(REPLACE('ABCDAAARSTRLAMA', 'A', '')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select len('ABCDAAARSTRLAMA') - len(replace('ABCDAAARSTRLAMA', 'A', ''))
```

This would give the count of 'A' from the string